# How to search for a string in array of arrays using javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

This function is able to search for a string in an array:

```
public checkElement( array ) {        
    for(var i = 0 ; i< array.length; i++) {
        if( array[i] == 'some_string' ) {
            return true;
        }      
    }
 }
```

How can i use array of arrays in the for loop? I want to pass this to a function that search a string with if condition.

Example input:
    `array[['one','two'],['three','four'],['five','six']]`.

Comment: kindly google for more sub tasks in your holistic task, e.g- how to compare string in java script and how to iterate over multi-dimentional arrays in javascript. Hope this will help.

Comment: btw, where do you get `public` from?

Comment: I use typescript class. So there i define the method as public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the "find" method instead

```
let arr = [['one','two'],['three','four'],['five','six']];

function searchInMultiDim(str) {
    return arr.find(t => { return t.find(i => i === str)}) && true;
}

searchInMultiDim('one');
```

Comment: Notice that this solution only good for 2 level depth - may be better to handle deeper levels also - or at least mention that in the answer

Comment: @DavidWinder According to the question, I don't think need to mention anything :) but of course making it generic would be efficient

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive solution that checks if an item is an array, and if it is searches it for the string. It can handle multiple levels of nested arrays.

```js
function checkElement(array, str) {
  var item;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    item = array[i];
    
    if (item === str || Array.isArray(item) && checkElement(item, str)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

var arr = [['one','two'],['three','four'],['five','six']];

console.log(checkElement(arr, 'four')); // true
console.log(checkElement(arr, 'seven')); // false
```

And the same idea using `Array.find()`:

```js
const checkElement = (array, str) =>
  !!array.find((item) =>
    Array.isArray(item) ? checkElement(item, str) : item === str
  );

const arr = [['one','two'],['three','four'],['five','six']];

console.log(checkElement(arr, 'four')); // true
console.log(checkElement(arr, 'seven')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
function checkElement(array){        
 for(value of array){
  if(value.includes("some string")){return true}
 }
 return false
}
console.log(checkElement([["one","two"],["three","four"],["five","six"]]))
console.log(checkElement([["one","two"],["three","four"],["five","some string"]]))
```